# Testing React components at different levels of abstraction

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing a ReactJS app using Jest + react-testing-library.

I have a `Dialog` component that encapsulates a button and a dialog, and that receives a `onSave` prop that gets called when a "Save" button is clicked.
Then I have a `Dashboard` parent component that renders a `Dialog` component and passes it a callback to its `onSave` prop.

The tests for `Dialog` are the following:

- When pressing the button, it shows the modal dialog
- When pressing Save, it calls whatever function is passed to its onSave prop

The tests for `Dashboard` are the following:

- It shows a button titled "Open dialog".
- When clicking that button and pressing "Save", it calls the callback passed (e.g. update an object state).

My problem is with the 2nd test for the Dashboard. It responds to the need for testing if the developer has wired correctly the component (having set up the callback that e.g. will update the `Dashboard` object state with the data coming from the `Dialog` component inner form). 
However, in order to implement that test, I have to mock any inner calls to the webapi that are made by `Dialog` so it renders correctly. To me, that is kind of wrong, as I should not need to know the inner workings of `Dialog` (i.e. which service calls to mock) in order to test its usage.

I can think of two approaches:

1. Mock the service calls (to webapi) that are made inside the `Dialog` component (making the test depend on the `Dialog` implementation and not the interface only).
2. Mock the `Dialog` component to make it "follow the contract" in the sense that "a component that shows a button with some label, that when clicked shows a Save button that, when clicked, calls a function provided to its onSave prop".

Looks like 2 makes more sense, but maybe it is too much and maybe I am missing something, specially since the "philosofy" of react-testing-library is to test the generated DOM (e.g. not relying on shallow rendering) and its interactions.

Comment: This is difficult to answer in the abstract - what are the API calls Dialog is making, why are they its responsibility? If it's for some kind of config, maybe that should be provided by a _context_ you can provide in the tests?

Comment: I don't think that matters. I can assure the calls made are its responsibility. For example, Dialog makes a query in the form of customerService.getDataById(id) so it can fill the inner form with values coming from the database.

AFAIK, from the Dashboard pov (and its test), it should not matter whether or not the Dialog is making any service calls, but I may be mistaken. That is important for the responsible of writing the Dialog test class, where I see the obvious need to mock those service calls.